# How to configure Eclipse for C#

Tags: c#, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Juno and windows 8. I want to configure C# for juno because eclipse is easier than other Frameworks and it has c/c++/java etc.. but not C# so is anyone got an idea about this situation?

Comment: I guess SharpDevelop would be another alternative, if one doesn't want to use Visual Studio for some reason.

Comment: If you are developing for .NET you should be on Windows, the only IDE worth writing C# in is Visual Studio. If you want something open you could use monodevelop, but then you shouldn't be using .net anyway.

Comment: @WilliamTioWeeLeong VS isn't open-source.

Comment: Yes, let's all start flaming the poor guy. SO should be more like reddit anyways, right?

Comment: Because we all know that Eclipse isn't a tool used primarily for programming

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eclipse is an IDE, not a "Framework". Juno is a version release of Eclipse (specifically, version 4.2, note that we're now up to Kepler which is 4.3).

Eclipse is not a C#/.NET IDE, it's primarily a Java and C/C++ IDE.

You can add C# support to Eclipse through a third-party plugin: http://emonic.sourceforge.net/ but I can't find any information regarding the efficacy of this plugin.

If you want a good C# IDE, install Visual C# Express: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

If you don't want to use Visual Studio, then use MonoDevelop: http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Wow I really did not expect there to be a plugin, kind of hoped intelliJ and AndroidStudio were killing it off +1

Comment: Xamarin studio is a good ide as well.

Comment: actually i can use mono, you right

Comment: MonoDevelop is not a good alternative. It lacks so many features, normal IDEs have since years. For example split view of two or more source files.

Comment: @Dai -1 because Eclipse is an application platform without any knowledge about programming languages. JDT, CDT and other features add programming support to the platform. Usually people download a distribution/bundle of Eclipse platform and one or more features. Most common is the distribution "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" which includes JDT (Java Development Tools).

Comment: @KaiK. Agree. Eclipse is an RCP (rich client platform). NetBeans is another popular example.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend using Eclipse for C#.

There are solutions out there for eclipse that lets you have syntax highlighting for C#, but i'm not sure of it's compilation abilities.

Also, why use Eclipse when VS already has so much. I mean hell, Microsoft made the language, and their software is ideal for it.

Not to mention, VS has very extravagant WinForms customization.  Nothing would compare even if eclipse did come out with something.

If you'd like your VS C# Express to operate like eclipse, (keybinds, color, etc)  then you can do that yourself, and customize the options.  I myself LOVE eclipse.. but it cannot stand on it's toes against the beast that is Visual Studio.

Check out [this article..](http://ifedeli.com/2006/07/11/add-ons-to-make-visual-studio-2005-feel-more-like-eclipse/)  it's written by a person that likes eclipse, but programs in VS. might help you get started.

Comment: C# is a CRL specific language and there are platform that emulate the CLR mainly Mono that allow C# to run on platforms other than windows.

Comment: Just a guess, but probably because it doesn't actually answer the question. "Don't do that" or "do this instead of what you asked" is probably better as a comment.

Comment: Not an actual anwer to the exact question, but this gives useful info on why there is no such answer