# Is it possible to generate getters/setters/constructors/ToString for C# in Sublime Text?

Tags: c#, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I am having a good experience with Sublime Text, but I am missing some features of Eclipse, like code generation. Is it possible in Sublime to generate simple code, like props, constructors etc?

**upd** i mean not just generate a method signature like ToString(), but autoadd all fields in it.

Comment: Write your own extension and it might help.

Comment: Repeat after me: ***"Sublime Text is not an IDE."*** It is possible to write an extended snippet or plugin that takes your class name or a property name and generates all these methods for you. You should search [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search) to look for things like that, not ask on here. However, please read the first line again. And once more, just to make sure. Sublime is NOT an IDE. It does not to code analysis and introspection for every Tom, Dick, and Harry programming language out there. It is a glorified text editor. Extendable, yes. Awesome, yes. But an IDE? No.

Comment: @MattDMo I found Eclipse is convinient, but my favorit IDE is Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can improve your experience on Sublime by using the "Snippets" feature.

As mentioned earlier, there are some ["ready-to-use" Snippets](https://packagecontrol.io/search/snippets)

But you can always build your own (that might suit your needs in a better way). Here's the official documentation from Sublime: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

p.s: The question is tagged C#, but the author mentions Eclipse.. God, I didn't know that such thing was possible.. but it is: [how to configure Eclipse for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979357/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-c-sharp)

Comment: actually i meant "like in eclipse", generate setters etc. :)