# using eclipse for unity 3d development

Tags: eclipse, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is it possible to write full function unity/C# code with `eclipse` instead of `MonoDevelop` and `visual studio`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you got your reasons to torture yourself (Mono and VS are free and easy to use). 
Anyway you may use whatever you want for editing C# code - Unity still uses its own C# compiler to compile your scripts, as explained here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html

You should configure eclipse for C# and create eclipse project in your unity project folder. Check out here:
[how to configure Eclipse for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979357/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-c-sharp)
there are C# plugins for eclipse for highlighting and so on.